# Variable is un-defined

Tags: php

I am having some difficulties with this problem. When I try to run this code, it says `Notice: Undefined variable: errors in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bots\botanize.php on line 5` and `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bots\botanize.php on line 5` but I am not sure how. I tried different ways, but they won't work. Any ideas?

```
 <?php 
$errors = array();
$error_num = 1;
function checkErrors(){
    foreach($errors as $e){
        if(count($errors)>0){
            echo "Error " . $error_num . ": " . $e . "<br />";
        }
        die();
    }
}
function curl_connection($website, $method, $data){
    if(strlen($website) < 1){
        array_push($errors, "The first parameter is not filled out!");
    }

    if(strlen($method) < 1){
        array_push($errors, "The second parameter is not filled out!");
    }

    if(strlen($data) < 1){
        array_push($errors, "The third parameter is not filled out!");
    }

    if(is_array($data)){
        array_push($errors, "The third parameter needs an array. Not a variable.");
    }

    if($method != 'POST' || $method != 'GET'){
        array_push($errors, "The second parameter needs a method type of POST or GET. Make sure the POST or GET is all capitalized.");
    }
}

checkErrors();

?>
```

Comment: `$errors` inside `checkErrors()` is undefined due to be out of scope

Comment: I know, but I can't put it in the function. It will fix the error but it won't do I what I want it to do.

Comment: `function checkErrors($errors){`  and `checkErrors($errors);` is all you need

Comment: @nogad Wow thanks a lot. If you post that as an answer I will vote it as best answer.